# Missing PowerShell Commands in SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I installed SharePoint Foundation 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2. I notice that no SP cmdlets are available in the PowerShell.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that the snapins aren't loaded in your powershell session.

Try this command:

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

Comment: That worked! I wonder why that is not installed by default...

Comment: There's probably a certain console window you have to open that might be somewhere in the programs menu.  If you are going to be doing this alot, I'd suggest adding a powershell profile (google profile.ps1) with that command in it.

Answer (score 0):

It is installed by default, but it is not loaded into your profile by default.  You can add it so it always loads by editing one of the default Powershell profiles.  From within Powershell, run `help profile` to find out more about which profile to use.